# change Font-family of sharepoint 2013 quick launch

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, css, quick-launch

I need to change the style of Quick Launch title,
What's the class of the title's style of sharepoinnt 2013 Quick Launch to add my font-family

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always use F12 developer tools in your browser to see what class the element is inheriting from.

Comment: I Did it to change font-size, but when I try to change font-family it doesn't work. I don't know how to read the tag for a level "x" in Quick launch

Comment: Are you using a more specific selector? Just try to specify the selector more or (easy and bad way) put !important on the property

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be two classes:

- .ms-core-list-menu
- .ms-core-navigation

They both can come into play depending on if you have manual or automatic left hand nav generation of links.

If you change .ms-core-navigation, it will also change the top bar links.